# problem in multi tasking program in iOS4

Tags: iphone

My application is entering into applicationDidEnterBackground method when i tapped on home button but the functions that i wrote in that method are not getting executed or called, can any one help me regarding this, I am trying this to make a application that is to run in back ground...?

Comment: Might wanna read here in the section "executing code in background": http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your application one of the 3 types that CAN run in the background?
i.e. Location, Music, or VoIP?

If not this may be why. If it is then what are you trying to do in the applicationDidEnterBackground method?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply dude...
Actually my application was not dealing with any of the 3 (location, music, VoIP)...
Here i need to complete a task that need more time to be in back ground running state...
I will be very thankful to u if u help me in back ground running state handling...

waiting for reply...